# How to send a panel to the back of an internal frame?

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, menubar

I have a JDesktopPane with a panel drawn inside.
I also have a help menu on the top.

When it draws the panel, it draws it on top of the menubar, blocking the menubar.

How can I send the panel to the back, unblocking the menubar?

Here is the constructor.

```
public Desktop () {
   Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
   Dimension scrnsize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
   desktop.setBackground(Color.orange); 
   desktopFrame.setContentPane(desktop);
   desktopFrame.addKeyListener(this);
   desktopFrame.setVisible(true);
   desktopFrame.setSize(scrnsize);

   desktopBackground = new JPanel();
   desktopBackground.setLocation(30 , 10);
   desktopBackground.setSize(100, 110);
   desktopBackground.setBackground(Color.red);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);       

    menuBar.add(startButton);       
    startButton.add(programsButton);        
    programsButton.add(terminalButton);
    desktopFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    terminalButton.addActionListener(this);

    desktop.add(menuBar);
    desktop.add(desktopBackground);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The menu bar shouldn't even be in a location where an internal panel or component can block it. If this is a JFrame application, then the JMenuBar should be added directly to the JFrame via its `setJMenuBar(...)` method. Then the JDesktopPane could be added to the JFrame BorderLayout.CENTER, and the JInternalFrames added to the JDesktopPane. This way there is no chance of covering the menu bar.

Comment: Maybe an inadvertent `frame.setContentPane()` instead of `frame.add()` elsewhere in the code?